# Expand variable within here-string in single quote using powershell

Tags: powershell, herestring

I have a scenario where I am using here-string with single quotes since I need to print the variable as it is and also expand certain variables within it. Can you please suggest how I can achieve this?

```
$S3BucketName = "Dynamically generated"
$file = "Dynamically generated" 

#This is for remote execution
$UserDataInput = @'
$Instance = "Dynamically generated"
Read-S3Object -BucketName $S3BucketName -Key "Path\$file.pem" -File "C:\Temp\$file.pem"
$Pass=Get-EC2PasswordData -InstanceId $Instance -PemFile "C:\Temp\$file.pem"
'@
```

The actual value of here string should look as below:

```
    $Instance = "Dynamically generated"
    Read-S3Object -BucketName testbucket -Key "Path\testfile.pem" -File "C:\Temp\testfile.pem"
    $Pass=Get-EC2PasswordData -InstanceId $Instance -PemFile "C:\Temp\testfile.pem"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ExecutionContext ExpandString](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions#executioncontext-expandstring) for this.
The difficulty thou, is in the "*expand **certain** variables*". Meaning that you will need to differentiate between the ones you want to expand and the ones you want to escape (with a backtick: `` `$DontExpand ``):

```
$S3BucketName = "MyBucket"
$file = ".\MyFile.pem" 

#This is for remote execution
$UserDataInput = @'
`$Instance = "Dynamically generated"
Read-S3Object -BucketName $S3BucketName -Key "Path\$file.pem" -File "C:\Temp\$file.pem"
`$Pass=Get-EC2PasswordData -InstanceId `$Instance -PemFile $file
'@

 $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($UserDataInput)
```

```
$Instance = "Dynamically generated"
Read-S3Object -BucketName MyBucket -Key "Path\.\MyFile.pem.pem" -File "C:\Temp\.\MyFile.pem.pem"
$Pass=Get-EC2PasswordData -InstanceId $Instance -PemFile .\MyFile.pem
```