Modifying the Write-host output in Powershell
I want to remove the single quotes at the beginning and end like desired output. And I want to enclose this part “C:\Windows\System32\wusa.exe” in double quotes.  How can I do that ?
Here is my script :
$Paths = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\KBUPDATE2016" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$counter = 0
Write-Host "!!! Run below commands on Windows Server 2016 machines"
foreach($path in $Paths){

$logfilename = "wusa" + $counter

Write-Host "'Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\wusa.exe" -ArgumentList 'C:\KBUPDATE2016\$path /quiet /norestart /Log:C:\KBUPDATE2016\$($logfilename).log' -Wait'"
$counter ++
}

My output :
!!! Run below commands on Windows Server 2016 machines
'Start-Process -FilePath  C:\Windows\System32\wusa.exe -ArgumentList 'C:\KBUPDATE2016\windows10.0-kb5036609-x64-ndp48_087fa1e62da956ae7e7fc0f994321e00a59cf1cf.ms
u /quiet /norestart /Log:C:\KBUPDATE2016\wusa0.log' -Wait'
'Start-Process -FilePath  C:\Windows\System32\wusa.exe -ArgumentList 'C:\KBUPDATE2016\windows10.0-kb5036899-x64_55391ef83ffb9a029d2489da756a3fb562d4e600.msu /qui
et /norestart /Log:C:\KBUPDATE2016\wusa1.log' -Wait'
'Start-Process -FilePath  C:\Windows\System32\wusa.exe -ArgumentList 'C:\KBUPDATE2016\windows10.0-kb5037016-x64_dde96790d66ed77a63239fd5a8e69db88c626029.msu /qui
et /norestart /Log:C:\KBUPDATE2016\wusa2.log' -Wait'

My Desired Output :
!!! Run below commands on Windows Server 2016 machines
Start-Process -FilePath  "C:\Windows\System32\wusa.exe" -ArgumentList 'C:\KBUPDATE2016\windows10.0-kb5036609-x64-ndp48_087fa1e62da956ae7e7fc0f994321e00a59cf1cf.ms
u /quiet /norestart /Log:C:\KBUPDATE2016\wusa0.log' -Wait
Start-Process -FilePath  "C:\Windows\System32\wusa.exe" -ArgumentList 'C:\KBUPDATE2016\windows10.0-kb5036899-x64_55391ef83ffb9a029d2489da756a3fb562d4e600.msu /qui
et /norestart /Log:C:\KBUPDATE2016\wusa1.log' -Wait
Start-Process -FilePath  "C:\Windows\System32\wusa.exe" -ArgumentList 'C:\KBUPDATE2016\windows10.0-kb5037016-x64_dde96790d66ed77a63239fd5a8e69db88c626029.msu /qui
et /norestart /Log:C:\KBUPDATE2016\wusa2.log' -Wait


What happens if you remove them from the Write-Output statement?  "Start-Process -FilePath ... -Wait"

I don't want to run Start-process directly here. I want to get the output of the commands that will run first.

If you don’t want the surrounding single quotes, just remove them… Write-Host "Start-Process … -Wait”. To get the inner double quotes to be treated as part of the literal string you can either double them up - write-host "...""..." or escape them with a backtick - write-host "...`"...”

You can use ExecutionContext ExpandString to just expand the variables and not invoking the whole expression. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75295475/1701026

Using double quotes inside double quotes?
# "`"...`""
"`"C:\Windows\System32\wusa.exe`""

Write-Host "Start-Process -FilePath "`"C:\Windows\System32\wusa.exe`"" -ArgumentList 'C:\KBUPDATE2016\$path /quiet /norestart /Log:C:\KBUPDATE2016\$($logfilename).log' -Wait"


The Output:
Start-Process -FilePath  "C:\Windows\System32\wusa.exe" -ArgumentList 'C:\KBUPDATE2016\ /quiet /norestart /Log:C:\KBUPDATE2016\.log' -Wait

Other options:
"`'...`'"
"`[...`]"
"`|...`|"


Note that your command string is being treated as 2 separate parameters to Write-Host, namely (i) ”Start-Process -FilePath “ and (ii) "C:\Windows\System32\wusa.exe`"" -ArgumentList                        'C:\KBUPDATE2016\$path /quiet /norestart                        /Log:C:\KBUPDATE2016\$($logfilename).log' -Wait" - this is because of the -FilePath "`"C:\… - you can see the effect as two space characters between these strings in the output from write-host. If you inspect the AST for the command you’ll see one is a double-quoted string and one is a bare word.
